# Scrolling multiple images in android

Tags: android, scroll, imageview

I´m writing an application for Android in which I have a character that I must dress with multiple items, such as clothes, hairs, hats, earrings, etc. and on one side of the screen I need to have a container with many items inside that are available for use.

My problem is that I haven´t found any object that lets me do this simple task in android, I need it to be scrollable, and resizeable so I can place it on the right of the screen, the objects i need to add are Imageviews.

I accomplished this on iPhone with a UIScrollView but it seems that it't not that simple with Android.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will use a ScrollView too, but you need embed a container of your images, like a Layout or Webview inside your ScrollView.

Comment: Thanks @Jorgesys, I used a RelativeLayout inside the ScrollView and add the items to it, now it all runs smoothly!!

Comment: ups I remember, i think the best way is using a WebView instead of ScrollView!